# Qt+OpenCV: Symbols not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5

I want to use the stereo-module of OpenCV, programming with Qt. When building my project, i get the following errors:

[image: building output]

[image: error output]

**My setup:**

- OpenCV 4.3.0 + contrib 4.3.0 compiled from source, used CMake GUI to make
- Qt Creator 4.11.0, Based on Qt 5.14.0 (Clang 10.0 (Apple), 64 bit)

**My pro-file:**

[image: Qt-project pro-file]

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for **StereoSGBM** it is part of the **calib3d** module, which is part of the **contrib** that you have mentioned already have.

I see you have linked against core, imgproc, imgcodecs and highgui but the calib3d is missing.